# Android ViewPager - floating action button clicks

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have the `ViewPager` and the floating action button in my `MainActivity`. Each fragment in the `ViewPager` is a 6x6 `GridLayout`. On button click, I want to start animation moving `ImageView` inside the `GridLayout`. Start and target positions are predefined in the list.

```
mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager)
mViewPager.adapter = mSectionsPagerAdapter
mViewPager.currentItem = currentFragment

val fab: View = findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton)
fab.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View) {
      val c =  mViewPager.currentItem
      val fromView = grid.getChildAt(fromList[c]) as ImageView
      val toView = grid.getChildAt(toList[c]) as ImageView
      val anim = TranslateAnimation(0f, toView.x - fromView.x, 0f, toView.y - fromView.y).apply {
          duration = 500
          fillAfter = false
      }
      fromView.startAnimation(anim)
}
```

Animation works as expected, but the problem is that it works only on the first page. When I swap to other pages and click the button, nothing happens. When I get back to the first page, also nothing happens. Can someone explain why this is so? How do I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: try after removing this line `mViewPager.currentItem = currentFragment`

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of how many "pages" you have in your application, you can set the *offscreenpagesize*. What happens is sometimes on swiping the pages out of focus, the context of those fragments could be lost.

```
viewPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(<number of fragments 'tabs'>);
```

[View more details of this method here.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Besides, I have several dozens of pages and don't want to keep them all active.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several pages then do not use `setOffscreenPageLimit`

**Try to add `fab.setOnClickListener` in each fragment.**

Comment: @D.S. Happy to help. Accept my answer if it useful :)